# does not checking for faulty function have potential security implications?

Tags: python, security, overflow

Hello there Pythonists,

A question hit my mind and I googled it around but didn't have any luck finding an answer for it. Consider the following python messy code:

```
print("hello World") 
x,y=3,4
def whatver(d,f):
    kjsafnsfoweifho
z=x+y
print (z)
```

python doesnt check the `whatever(d,f)`function, i wonder if such a thing could be a security breach for hackers as statically typed languages would never allow the program run unless the check that everything inside the body of source code is a valid programming code. I am writing about the downsides of python in terms of security. if this cause a security breach i'd love to know the kind and what are the potential implications

Comment: if you're looking for the potential breaches, I suggest you rather look into the `eval` function (also `exec`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong syntax is one problem, people being able to inject arbitrary code into your application logic is a completely different issue you face in almost all languages. Maybe the problem is bigger in languages allowing monkey-patching, but the general question stays the same: how would anyone inject methods into your code? It shouldn't happen if you don't import user-generated modules or call eval.